# Source = "dsk" not working for the geocode function in the ggmap library

Tags: r, api, ggmap, geocode

The datasciencetoolkit.org has terminated its maps service from 12 feb'19. Anyone else experiencing the same issue? Moreover is there any other simple way to geocode  locations in R as using GoogleAPI requires a billing account

Comment: Yes, if they've terminated that service, everyone will have that issue, i.e. it's no longer available for anyone

Answer (score 1):

A few options in R:

- geonames: https://github.com/ropensci/geonames/ (use dev version from github, cran version broken)
- opencage: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/opencage/

Don't know about an R pkg, but just saw https://locationiq.com/docs-html/index.html#official-client-libraries

Comment: geonames seems to work great and to be really complete.  Finding examples is harder though.  Here is an example of geocoding a city: `rouyn.coo <- GNsearch(q="Rouyn Noranda", country = "CA", cities = "cities1000")`.  I may help other people coming here.